# Delphi: Capture OSX console output

Tags: delphi, console

I am on OSX and I found the following Delphi (Firemonkey) code to write the console output to a Memo. This works fine when I am using normal commands like "ls", but it doesn't capture the output from external terminal apps.

For example, if I run the command line application "youtube-dl", the output shows up only in the PAServer log, but not in the Memo.

Is there a way to do this? Or can someone modify the code to make this work?

```
const
  libc = '/usr/lib/libc.dylib';

type
  PIOFile = Pointer;

//Create a new stream connected to a pipe running the given command.
function popen(const Command: PAnsiChar; Modes: PAnsiChar): PIOFile; cdecl;
  external libc name '_popen';

//Close a stream opened by popen and return the status of its child.
function pclose(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name '_pclose';

//Return the EOF indicator for STREAM.
function feof(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name '_feof';

//Read chunks of generic data from STREAM.
function fread(Ptr: Pointer; Size: LongWord; N: LongWord;
  Stream: PIOFile): LongWord; cdecl; external libc name '_fread';

//Wait for a child to die.  When one does, put its status in *STAT_LOC
//and return its process ID.  For errors, return (pid_t) -1.
function wait(__stat_loc: PInteger): Integer; cdecl;
  external libc name '_wait';

procedure TForm1.ExecCmdine(const CmdLine: string);
var
  Output: PIOFile;
  Buffer: PAnsiChar;
  TempString: Ansistring;
  Line: AnsiString;
  BytesRead: Integer;
const
  BufferSize: Integer = 1000;
begin
  TempString := '';
  Output := popen(PAnsiChar(Ansistring(CmdLine)), 'r');
  GetMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
  if Assigned(Output) then
  try
    while feof(Output) = 0 do
    begin
      BytesRead := fread(Buffer, 1, BufferSize, Output);
      SetLength(TempString, Length(TempString) + BytesRead);
      Move(Buffer^, TempString[length(TempString) - (BytesRead - 1)], BytesRead);

      while Pos(#10, TempString) > 0 do
      begin
        Line := Copy(TempString, 1, Pos(#10, TempString) - 1);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(UTF8ToString(Line));

        TempString := Copy(TempString, Pos(#10, TempString) + 1, Length(TempString));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    pclose(output);
    wait(nil);
    FreeMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does anything come from output? If it does... Why does necessary cmdresult? Doesn't utf8tostring pass back an empty string? (due to invalid char codes)?  Do unit tests for all branches.

Comment: the command I run (youtube-dl) works and it downloads the video, but I want to do different things with the console output. For example a process bar or I want to see the available video formats, and so on. I don't think the utf8tostring is the problem because I added a showmessage('test') in the while loop at position "while Pos(#10, TempString) > 0 do" for test purposes and it never shows up. so the while loop seems to be never true.

Comment: made the concatenation simpler. tempString := tempString + strPas( buffer^ )

Comment: if the replacestring function available in you compiler : replaceString( tempString, CONST_chars_NewLine, '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase] );

Comment: This gives me "There is no overloaded version of 'StrPas' that can be called with these arguments" ... My coding skills are very low, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: modify the type of the buffer to pchar and tempstring and line to string.

Comment: I modified buffer, tempstring and line, but It doesn't change anything.

Comment: stringreplace doesn't work because CONST_chars_NewLine is unknown

Comment: yes. it is just a name of a const for the new line chars. but it depends on your OS : #10#13 or #13#10. define it in the right way. const CONST_chars_NewLine = #13 #10; (for windows)

Comment: ah ok....on OSX it's  #10 (without #13), but still no output in the memo after stringreplace

Comment: Which part of this code doesn't work? Use your debugger and observe what happens. Take note we when a line of your code doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: @RobKennedy I don't know why but RAD Studio always freezes when I try to use the debugger on OSX. Other platforms are working. The problem is that "tempstring" is always empty when i run 'youtube-dl', but it's not empty if i run normal system commands like 'ls'

Comment: Are you sure youtube-dl prints its output to stdout? Maybe it goes to stderr, which `popen` doesn't capture. You can redirect stderr to stdout (like with `2>&1`), or you can use some other method of executing the program and capturing its output from both output streams separately.

Comment: @RobKennedy yeeeeees, thank you 1000 times :)))) i added 2>&1 and now it's working. Make an answer with this and I give you the upvote and mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Kennedy had the correct answer, but sadly he didn't post it as answer, so I will do it.

The problem was that the console output of youtube-dl gets printed to stderr and not stdout, so I had to add 2>&1 to the console command when running it.