# Run linux command line utility from delphi app and capture output

Tags: linux, delphi

How can I run a command line utility in Linux from a Delphi 10.2/10.3 application and capture the output for further processing?

I need the capturing to go line by line to watch the progress as I am going to use a GUI application with FMXLinux. This approach for OSX works perfectly

[Delphi: Capture OSX console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020737/delphi-capture-osx-console-output)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for voting down without explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example mentioned above created for OSX works perfectly on Linux64 (tested with current Ubuntu) with a small modification in the definitions. As the changes are small, I don't repeat the code (see [Delphi: Capture OSX console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020737/delphi-capture-osx-console-output)):

1. Add

   `Posix.Base`

   and

   `Posix.Fcntl`

   to uses clause
2. Remove line with path to libc.dylib
3. Change libc function declarations by exchanging the underscore by _PU:

   `... cdecl; external libc name _PU + 'popen'; ...`

Now it compiles and works for OSX and Linux as well!